# WebContent\WEB-INF\classes folder is empty. Java build path cannot find my classes

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error. Simple, but I can't solve it!

When I checked the folder

> WebContent\WEB-INF\classes

I saw it is empty. It means the classes cannot be built. 
I have a maven project and I did several times: Maven clean, Maven install, but still I have the same error. 
When I look to my Java Build Path windows, in the source tab, I see that default output folder is: MyProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes.
Also in this window the checkbox: Allow output folder for source folders **is not checked**, even I checked it and apply and save it, when I run the project, it will be automatically unchecked again. Strange! It seems something else is rewriting my build path.

Also you can see in my images that my Web deployment assembly seems to be correct. 

I clean Tomcat server and clean project and build it again. But it does not help.

My web.xml based on my project hierarchy image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>SimBio</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SimServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>simbio.main.SimServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SimServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SimServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I use Apache Tomcat 7.0, my project comes to

> HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class
>   simbio.main.SimServlet

> exception 
>  javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating
>   servlet class simbio.main.SimServlet
>   
> root cause
>  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   simbio.main.SimServlet

What is wrong with my project. What else should I check? 
I would appreciate your help.

[image: java build path]
[image: libraries]
[image: deployment assembely]
[image]

**Update:**
In Environment Variables I haves these:

> JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191 
>   JAVA_PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin

**Update2**
My pom.xml (it depends on other projects, if there is an error on running those Maven depenedcies projects, can my project gets an effect? Actually my project is old and these pom.xml referes to some version which are not exist)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>SimBio</groupId>
<artifactId>SimBio</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>jena-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
        <artifactId>sesame-model</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.sharispe</groupId>
        <artifactId>slib-graph</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.sharispe</groupId>
        <artifactId>slib-graph-model</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.sharispe</groupId>
        <artifactId>slib-utils</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.sharispe</groupId>
        <artifactId>slib-tools-sml-toolkit</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.sharispe</groupId>
        <artifactId>slib-sml</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.sharispe</groupId>
        <artifactId>slib-graph-algo</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Update3:** I think my problem related to other depenedt projects (which their maven currentlyy can't be install. I have one error in my error list, that say: build path is incomplite. 
[image: error]

Comment: Can you also post your pom.xml. You project structure doesn't seem to be aligned with Maven conventions (for ex. source files should be under src/main/java and src/main/webapp. Please refer to this guide - https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html

Comment: I added my pom.xml. My project uses the other existing project (it depends on the other). I checked now, in those project, pom.xml cannot be run. there is an error on them. I am trying to resolve them and run those pom.xml files, but so far, no result.

Comment: based on my entry of pom.xml, I also updated the image of deployment assembly.

Comment: Yes, I already also tried it with MyProject/target/classes, but the checkbox doesnot keep checked when I run the project. and also in target\classes, there is no files

Comment: Can you try using this in your <build> configurattion?<outputDirectory>WebContent/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to do it. Could you please explain it more? You mean in my first image, in the default output folder, write this?

Comment: It needs to be done in your pom.xml. You are using maven to build your project, right?

Comment: Yes, for the other connected projects, their Maven install shows: Received fatal alert: protocol_version error, I got it now, I can't solve it. When I resolve all other Maven install in all other pom.xml, then I can run also my project, yes? for my project maven install also shows some error to other related projects.

Answer (score 0):

**It Solved!** 
I do not know what help me exactly, but I did several changes, as a whole it solved my problem:

- When classes cannot be built, there is an error on pom.xml of the project and pom.xml of other related projects.
- When the checkbox of Allow output folders for source folders cannot hold, it means another thing is rewriting, so be sure to JAVA_HOME be the same as the project setting
- I also add the output folder as MyProject/target/classes
- I also checked the version of JDK/JRE in my project and other related projects and also Tomcat be the same.
- Compile error on my servlet class maybe also caused: Error instantiating servlet class